# How do I debug JSPs on remote JBoss server?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jboss, debugging

I'm debugging an application on a remote server running JBoss using Eclipse.  My particular problem is a `NullPointerException` in a JSP.  The JSP has too much Java code inside scriptlets but, unfortunately refactoring is not going to be an option.  Finding the line that throws the `NullPointerException` has been incredibly challenging and I'm getting stuck.

How can I debug this JSP remotely to find the line of the scriplet throwing the `NullPointerException`?

I ended up finding the problem by commenting out lines of the JSP until I isolated the issue.  Tedious but, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable remote debugging on some application servers by adding something like this

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5001,server=y,suspend=n
```

to the command line.  Then, in your IDE, connect to port 5001 for remote debugging.  [This page](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html) has some examples for various application servers.

I find that debugging JSPs can sometimes be done easily if you have the java source for the compiled JSPs.  Check your application server's manual for JSP compilation or pre-compile your JSPs and save the .java files; then use these files as the source for the debugger.

Comment: accepted because that's the correct command for starting JBoss to connect a remote debug session.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will be able to find the error on the server log. Since you are running it on a remote server, go to that machine and check the log. It should point out the error.

I find it easier to debug if I am running a local version of the site as I can monitor the server log through eclipse in real time. Perhaps it would be worth it to set up a local copy you can develop with and then just deploy to the remote server when you have fully debugged the code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Last line of the server log is:

NullPointerException at 
org.apache.jsp.myjsp._jspService(Unknown Source)

I can narrow down it's Java code in the jsp throwing the exception but can narrow down the line.

Comment: Sounds like the debugging symbols are stripped from that JSP. Even debugging won't help much.

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to do some manual debugging. Null tests and the like. Not pretty but effective.